# Invalid Identifier in Oracle Function

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function

This is my `SQL`;

```
select a.hesap_no, 
       a.teklif_no1 || '/' || a.teklif_no2 as teklif, 
       a.mus_k_isim as musteri, 
       b.marka, 
       c.sasi_no, 
       c.sasi_durum, 
       d.tas_mar, 
       nvl(risk_sasi(a.teklif_no1, a.teklif_no2, c.urun_sira_no, c.sira_no), 0) as risk,
       nvl(mv_sasi(a.teklif_no1, a.teklif_no2, c.sira_no, c.urun_sira_no, sysdate), 0) as mv
  from s_teklif a,  
       s_urun b, 
       s_urun_detay c, 
       koc_ktmar_pr d
 where a.teklif_no1 || a.teklif_no2 = b.teklif_no1 || b.teklif_no2
```

This is my `MV_SASI` Function;

```
create or replace
FUNCTION MV_SASI 
(
  TEK1 IN VARCHAR2,
 TEK2 IN NUMBER,
 SIRA IN NUMBER,
 USIRA IN NUMBER,
 DT IN DATE
) 
RETURN NUMBER IS MV number;

fat number;
adet number;
pd number;
pds number;
kt date;
ktv number;
dtv number;
frk number;
yfrk number;

TKM VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN       

SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO adet
  FROM S_URUN_DETAY
  WHERE (SASI_DURUM IS NULL OR SASI_DURUM IN ('A','R'))
  AND TEKLIF_NO1 = TEK1
  AND TEKLIF_NO2 = TEK2;

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN B.SASI_DURUM IS NULL OR B.SASI_DURUM IN ('A','R') THEN A.KDV_FIYAT ELSE 0 END)
  INTO fat
  FROM S_URUN A,S_URUN_DETAY B
    WHERE  A.TEKLIF_NO1 = tek1
    AND A.TEKLIF_NO2 = tek2
    AND A.TEKLIF_NO1 = B.TEKLIF_NO1
      AND A.TEKLIF_NO2 = B.TEKLIF_NO2
       AND A.SIRA_NO = B.URUN_SIRA_NO;

SELECT KULLAN_TARIH
INTO kt
FROM S_TEKLIF
 WHERE TEKLIF_NO1 = tek1
       AND TEKLIF_NO2 = tek2 ; 

yfrk:= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM kt);

  ktv := EXTRACT(MONTH FROM kt);
  dtv := EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt);

  frk := yfrk * 12 + (dtv-ktv);

IF frk  <= 0 THEN
  pd := fat * 0.85;
ELSE
  pd := fat*0.85 - (fat * 0.0101 * frk);
END IF;

SELECT NVL(ROUND((CASE WHEN SASI_DURUM IS NULL OR SASI_DURUM IN ('A','R') THEN pd / adet ELSE 0 END),2),0)
INTO pds
FROM S_URUN_DETAY
WHERE TEKLIF_NO1 = TEK1
AND TEKLIF_NO2 = TEK2
AND URUN_SIRA_NO = USIRA
AND SIRA_NO = SIRA;

RETURN pds;

END;
```

But in my page i getting an error with this line of code;

```
 OracleDataReader dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

[image]

Where am i doing wrong?

Best Regards, Soner

myCommand is;

```
select a.hesap_no, 
       a.teklif_no1 || '/' || a.teklif_no2 as teklif, 
       a.mus_k_isim as musteri, 
       b.marka, 
       c.sasi_no, 
       c.sasi_durum, 
       d.tas_mar, 
       nvl(risk_sasi(a.teklif_no1, a.teklif_no2, c.urun_sira_no, c.sira_no), 0) as risk,
       nvl(mv_sasi(a.teklif_no1, a.teklif_no2, c.sira_no, c.urun_sira_no, sysdate), 0) as mv
  from s_teklif a,  
       s_urun b, 
       s_urun_detay c, 
       koc_ktmar_pr d
 where a.teklif_no1 || a.teklif_no2 = b.teklif_no1 || b.teklif_no2
   and a.teklif_no1 || a.teklif_no2 = c.teklif_no1 || c.teklif_no2
   and b.sira_no = c.urun_sira_no
   and b.distributor = d.dist_kod
   and b.marka = d.marka_kod
   and b.urun_kod = d.tas_kod  
   and a.hesap_no in (select a.hesap_no 
                        from s_teklif a 
                       where a.mus_k_isim in (system.collections.arraylist)
                     )
```

Comment: Can you rule out MV_SASI being the issue by running a query like "select MV_SASI(.... enter values ....) from dual"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit at the end of your SQL seems odd:  `WHERE A.MUS_K_ISIM IN (System.Collections.ArrayList)`.  If that's really your actual SQL text, then I think this is your problem.  Oracle has no idea what `System.Collections.ArrayList` is.

Moreover, if what you're trying to do is bind an actual arraylist into the SQL so that you can test against it with `IN` -- that won't work.  Even if you successfully got it to bind to a known datatype in Oracle, the syntax of `IN` is such that the operand is compared to each element in a comma-delimited list of identifiers -- Oracle won't break the list apart for you.

You either need to bind each item of the list so you have a condition like `A.MUS_K_ISIM IN (:bind1, :bind2, :bind3)`, or map your arraylist to a nested table or varray type in Oracle so you can use a subquery with IN, like `A.MUS_K_ISIM IN (SELECT columnValue FROM TABLE(CAST(:bindlist AS someOracleType)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I have come accross that kind of problem a short time ago. The problem was:

Stupid oracle has not a stacktrace type error handling mechanism so it only gives the top error, which prevents us to see the other ones.

Your function MV_SASI has no grant to be used by the oracle user. So Oracle could not find it and tried to run it like MV_SASI is a column name. so it gives the error.

Check the grant and visibility settings of the MV_SASI func.

Comment: @Ali But this sql is working SELECT NVL(MV_SASI('K07', 348, 1, 1, SYSDATE),0) FROM DUAL

Comment: Did u run it with the user that the application uses? And I found another func:RISK_SASI.

Comment: @Ali I control both function but there is no error with them.

Comment: Are u sure that u are using exactly the same user with the application uses?

Comment: SO u can run it the whole query (in your question I mean) with the user that application uses and u had no error in TOAD? Or u got the same error?